# BIND Whitelist Config

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, whitelist

Im trying to setup a 'whitelist' DNS server for a small school network to prevent the kids accessing *inappropriate* sites (ie. students should only be able to access a pre-selected list of sites) and be forwarded to an access-denied page if they try accessing such a page.

Im aware this can be done using Squid3 but in this specific case its not a viable option.

I read the man named page as well as a number of tech sites and Im not having much luck. If any one could give me  nudge in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

-Cheers

Answer (score 2):

BIND is really unsuited to this scenario, since it is primarily a large-scale authoritative nameserver.

You could, of course, define forward zones for everything you wish to whitelist, and then have those zones resolved by a second instance, but that is convoluted beyond measure.

Just use a proxy with good access control, such as Squid-cache.

Comment: Unfortunately we cant use squid (as mentioned) for banwidth reasons. but if you have any other possible solutions I would really love to hear them. as it stands I think I will be using powerdns

Comment: -1 Your answer is to use something the OP said wasn't possible.